# Appending an XML file for multiple files

Tags: xml, vb.net, file

So, I have this program that gathers 'source', 'destination', and 'job name' from a user and then adds this information to an XML file in this type of manner

```
-<Jobs> -<Job> <JobName>a</JobName> 
<Source>C:\Users\Public\Pictures\SamplePictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg</Source> 
<Source>C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg</Source>
<Source>C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Hydrangeas.jpg</Source>  
<Destination>C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\a.zip</Destination> 
<Timestamp>11/23/2012 3:43:42 PM</Timestamp> </Job>
```

However, my issue comes from when i run the program a second time around. I want it to just collect the new information inputted in the program and append(add to) the XML file. However, when i run the program a second time the xml file only updates the source node for a single file (the last file read by the program)

Any help?
 Below is my code for the fJobDup() function.

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("C:\Users\Matt Taylor\Desktop\Backup\Backup.xml")
Dim job As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Job")
Dim jName As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("JobName")
Dim jsource As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Source")
Dim jdestin As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Destination")
Dim jtime As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Timestamp")

job.AppendChild(jName)
job.AppendChild(jsource)
job.AppendChild(jdestin)
job.AppendChild(jtime)
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(job)

jName.InnerText = JobName.Text.ToString()

Dim filesEnum3 As IEnumerator
filesEnum3 = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.GetEnumerator()


While filesEnum3.MoveNext

jsource.InnerText = filesEnum3.Current

End While

jdestin.InnerText = boxDestin.Text.ToString()
jtime.InnerText = Now()

doc.Save("C:\Users\Matt Taylor\Desktop\Backup\Backup.xml")
```

i already have a check for if the file exists or not. This comes in at the very end when i click the 'finish' button.

```
If Dir("C:\Users\Matt Taylor\Desktop\Backup\Backup.xml") <> "" Then
        fjobdup()
    Else
        fJob()
    End If
```

The fJobDup() function is the one i have listed at the top of this thread.

And the following code is the fJob() function.

```
    Dim Backxml As New XmlWriterSettings()
    Backxml.Indent = True
    Dim xmlwrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create =
    ("C:\Users\MattTaylor\Desktop\Backup\Backup.xml",   Backxml)

    Dim filesEnum2 As IEnumerator
    filesEnum2 = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.GetEnumerator()

    With xmlwrt
        .WriteStartDocument()
        .WriteComment("XML Backup.")
        .WriteStartElement("Jobs")

        .WriteStartElement("Job")

        Dim jName As String = JobName.Text.ToString
        .WriteElementString("JobName", jName.ToString)


        While filesEnum2.MoveNext
            .WriteStartElement("Source")
            .WriteString(filesEnum2.Current)
            .WriteEndElement()
        End While

        .WriteStartElement("Destination")
        .WriteString(boxDestin.Text)
        .WriteEndElement()

        .WriteStartElement("Timestamp")
        .WriteString(Now())
        .WriteEndElement()

        .WriteEndDocument()
        .Close()
    End With
```

If more code would help. This is the code for the button to add files to the Listbox (named boxSource).

```
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Dim filesEnum As IEnumerator

    filesEnum = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.GetEnumerator()

    While filesEnum.MoveNext
        boxSource.Items.Add(filesEnum.Current)
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new XMLDocument on every run.

try checking if the file exists.

See if this helps.. please verify the syntax once..

```
Dim doc as XmlDocument()

If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Users\Matt Taylor\Desktop\Backup\Backup.xml") Then
    doc.Load("C:\Users\Matt Taylor\Desktop\Backup\Backup.xml")
Else
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
End If
```

Comment: in that case, i guess you really should put some more code in here. where exactly are you putting the check? according to the code you have posted, a new instance of XmlDocument doc is created just before the doc.Load method. I guess it would be better if you could post some more code.

Comment: Ok, i gave you more code. All the code i think you should need. Now, keep in mind this is the first program i've ever written in VB and the first program i've written in at least 3 years. So i'm a bit rusty.

Comment: Is there anyone out there who has taken a gander at this have any clues for me?